# Why doesn't jwks(JSON Web Key Sets) standard just pass public key in pem form instead of the using modulus and exponent?

Tags: security, authentication, rsa, jwk

By the [JWKS standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517), public keys are exposed in the format of

```json
{
"keys": [
  {
    "alg": "RS256",
    "kty": "RSA",
    "use": "sig",
    "x5c": [
      "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"
    ],
    "n": "yeNlzlub94YgerT030codqEztjfU_S6X4DbDA_iVKkjAWtYfPHDzz_sPCT1Axz6isZdf3lHpq_gYX4Sz-cbe4rjmigxUxr-FgKHQy3HeCdK6hNq9ASQvMK9LBOpXDNn7mei6RZWom4wo3CMvvsY1w8tjtfLb-yQwJPltHxShZq5-ihC9irpLI9xEBTgG12q5lGIFPhTl_7inA1PFK97LuSLnTJzW0bj096v_TMDg7pOWm_zHtF53qbVsI0e3v5nmdKXdFf9BjIARRfVrbxVxiZHjU6zL6jY5QJdh1QCmENoejj_ytspMmGW7yMRxzUqgxcAqOBpVm0b-_mW3HoBdjQ",
    "e": "AQAB",
    "kid": "NjVBRjY5MDlCMUIwNzU4RTA2QzZFMDQ4QzQ2MDAyQjVDNjk1RTM2Qg",
    "x5t": "NjVBRjY5MDlCMUIwNzU4RTA2QzZFMDQ4QzQ2MDAyQjVDNjk1RTM2Qg"
  }
]}
```

Why don't we just do this instead?

```json
{
"keys": [
  {
    "alg": "RS256",
    "kty": "RSA",
    "use": "sig",
    "value": "-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----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-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----",
    "kid": "NjVBRjY5MDlCMUIwNzU4RTA2QzZFMDQ4QzQ2MDAyQjVDNjk1RTM2Qg"
  }
]}
```

Is there is specific reason in doing so? Is it because of the `Timing attack` and how does this format help with the timing attack?

Comment: What possible advantage could there be for PEM form? It's a much more complicated form to convey the same information.

Comment: @JamesKPolk you're right of course, but I think what the asker says still makes some sense, because people have keys in pem right away. It would be easier in some cases. However, this is all off topic for SO I'm afraid. :)

Comment: @JamesKPolk, I totally agree with @GaborLengyel because a lot of the functions provided can generate cert in PEM form right away. For example, the `generateKeyPair` function from the nodejs `crypto` library. It would be much easier to just send the generated certs.

Answer (score 0):

The `JWK` format have been created to have a compact JSON based format for all types of key types.

It is possible to have `RSA` and `EC` keys in PEM/DER formats, it is not possible for other key types like `OKP` and `oct` ones.

In any case, the conversion from the PEM to the JWK one is really straightforward.

I don't see any disadvantage with this key format regarding the timing attack.